# Delete line in file indicated by str user input

Tags: python

Text file:

```
1. line
2. line
3. line
4. line
...
```

code:

```
quit = False
while not quit:
    with open("sample.txt", "r+") as file:
        n = len(file.read().split("\n"))
        idea = input(f"Enter idea no. {n}: ")
        if idea == "--q":
            quit = True
        elif idea == "--list":
            with open("sample.txt", "r") as file:
                print(f"\n{file.read()}\n")
        elif idea == f"--del {type(int)}": #if user enter i.e. '--del 4' it dels line 4 
            with open("sample.txt", "r") as file:
                l = idea.split(" ")[1]
                lines = file.readlines()
                del lines[l]
            del_idea = open("sample.txt", "w")
            for line in lines:
                del_idea.write(line)
            del_idea.close()
        else:
            file.write(f"{n}. {idea}\n")
```

How to implement delete a line selected by user?

problematic line: `elif idea == f"--del {type(int)}"`

User wants to delete chosen line using syntax i.e `--del 4`, command **must be in one single line**. If a digit is not given  after blank " " (space) in input, **should loop until enters it properly**.

Any ideas? Should use regex ?

Comment: What is the question? Is there a problem? Are you getting an error? Wrong output? Please read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]

Comment: are you looking for `argparse`?

Comment: If your question is about the `elif idea == f"--del {type(int)}":` line then I think it would be better and easier to just do `elif idea.split()[0] == "--del":`... and then get the number by `idea.split()[1]`

Comment: @Tomerikoo - that's the point! Thanks it works

Comment: Check out the answer I made from this comment. If it solved your problem you can accept to don't leave the question open

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `f-strings` don't work like regex. `type(int)` is the actual `type` class so you're basically checking if the user literally input `"--del <class 'type'>"` (which is never the case I believe).

You can use regex to match a pattern of `del` followed by a number (i.e, `r"--del \d+"`), but an easier way would be to `split` the input and access the arg and number easily:

```py
quit = False
while not quit:
    with open("sample.txt", "r+") as file:
        n = len(file.read().split("\n"))
        idea = input(f"Enter idea no. {n}: ").split()
        if idea[0] == "--q":
            quit = True
        elif idea[0] == "--list":
            ...
        elif idea[0] == "--del":
            with open("sample.txt", "r") as file:
                l = idea[1]
                ...
        else:
            file.write(f"{n}. {idea}\n")
```